# RedirectToRoute doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm making my first web app. until now i haven't got any problems with redirectToRoute or redirectToAction. At the end of post action I want to redirect, but it doesn't work at all here is my code:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var post = this.Data
            .Posts
            .All()
            .Where(x => x.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (post != null)
        {
            var thread = this.Data
                .Threads
                .All()
                .Where(x => x.Id == post.ThreadId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            this.Data
                .Posts
                .Delete(post);

            this.Data.SaveChanges();

            return this.RedirectToRoute(CommonConstants.RedirectToRouteShowThread, new
            {
                area = "",
                id = thread.Id,
                title = thread.SubCategory.Title,
                name = thread.Title,
                action = "Display"
            });
            //return this.RedirectToRoute(CommonConstants.RedirectToRouteShowAllThreadsInSubCategory, new { Area = "", title = thread.SubCategory.Title });

            // return this.Redirect("red/red");
        }

        return this.View();
    }
```

I also tried different redirects just to test, but still doesn't work. I'am calling this action from js if it matters. Also I have checked if it goes inside If conditional, everything seems fine. Where is my error?

EDIT: Here are my routes

```
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Show thread",
            url: "SubCategory/{title}/{action}/{id}-{name}/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "Display", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ForumSystem.Web.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Create and display threads",
            url: "SubCategory/{title}/{action}/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "SubCategory", page = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ForumSystem.Web.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "ForumSystem.Web.Controllers" });
    }
```

and this is the const

```
    public static readonly string RedirectToRouteShowThread = "Show thread";
```

What I mean it doesn't work is that it doesn't redirect everything else is working as expected.

Comment: What does `CommonConstants.RedirectToRouteShowThread` return? Does it match a route name?

Comment: Post the signature of the action method as well.

Comment: Saying "doesn't work" does not help.  It is a completely useless statement of the problem that gives no hint of the actual cause or error.  If you want to ask questions here you will need to learn how to ask useful questions.

Comment: RedirectToRoute sends a 302 to the browser with the new URL. You should be able to see this in your browsers address bar. Use any browser debugging tool you like eg Fiddler, IE Developer tools, Google dev tools, to see what is returned to the browser.